# Parse iOS/OSX Local/Offline Database?

Tags: database, parse-platform, local, offline

Are there any good solutions to having offline/local access to my Parse database? Parse themselves announced 'Local Database' for Android in April and said iOS was coming soon, but I haven't heard anymore.

If I can't have an offline accessible database I'm going to have to use a different service.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is not a SO kind of Question, to check whether Local Database is for iOS released or not you should directly check the website or blog of Parse. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Parse announced local Datastare for iOS just a fiew days ago: [Parse Blog](http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/)

Offline Parse-DB is **still not available on iOS / OS X**.

You could try to sync the parse-db manually with a local db. An option would we **[FTASync](https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync)** or you could follow the tutorial available here: **[Ray Wenderlich - How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)**

Answer (score 0):

As purplej0kr mentioned, the functionality for offline parse storage does not yet exist for parse on iOS. What you can do is store the data into a sqlite database or into core data on your device. You can run a sync on app open or app exit in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Parse, I believe the only reasonable option is to count on them making LocalDataStore available on iOS. I tried using FTASync and discovered many problems with it. I actually wrote a complete sync engine for iOS and Parse, but junked it when LDS came out. Writing a good sync engine is a many engineering month job. The upside it that when LDS becomes available, it will be WAY easier to use that a sync engine implementation.